# Programmatically setting the system date and time in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've been looking over the new Windows Phone Runtime API and can't seem to find any API's for manipulating system settings...specifically the system date and time. Is this possible with the new API? I know it wasn't in WP 7.1

Answer (score 3):

> and can't seem to find any API's for manipulating system settings

Of course there is no such API. There's absolutely no reason why a 3rd party application should modify system settings. The user can already do that them self in the OS settings.

Comment: of course? I can do it on android. And yes, the user can manually set it, but there are applications for having a 3rd party app synchronise the time on the device...such as time based 2 factor auth. the Auto setting in date time only works if the cell carrier supports it, which my local one does not.

Comment: Yep, this hasn't changed since WP7.

Comment: Nonsense, the user can always change their date and time in settings.

Comment: There are cases when user has set his phone to 2010 by mistake or whatever the default date will be when resetting phone, but some certificates or applications require correct date to validate expiration. This possibility was sometimes quite handy in Symbian development.

Comment: Use a 3rd party clock service to make sure it's synced. If the user picks a "wrong" date, I'd hate your app to correct it.